# Apache shows PHP code instead of executing it

Tags: php, apache

I have recently been trying to install PHP and Apache on my computer. After many hours, they're installed. I have modified the httpd.conf and php.ini files like everyone says. I then created a simple PHP script:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

But when I try to run it with `http://127.0.0.1/phpinfo.php` it just shows the source code instead of executing it. I am using Apache 2, PHP 5 and Windows Vista.

EDITED LINES:

PHP.INI:

```
short_open_tag = On
```

HTTPD.CONF

```
LoadModule php5_module "C:/php/php5apache2_2.dll"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
PHPIniDir "C:/php"
```

Comment: in phpinfo.php have you added some headers that make's .php file readable?

Comment: @Peteris no my whole script is in my question

Comment: try simple script: `<?php echo "Hello world"; ?>` does it display Hello world? if it displays the code then how @RabNawaz sayed your server is not configured correctly!

Comment: Just displays the code again :(

Comment: from where are you accessing your php file? please note that in order to execute php file by your server you need to put your files in the proper web root directory. and access it in your web browser as `http://localhost/` or `http://127.0.0.1/`

Comment: why not directly install http://www.wampserver.com/en/ instead of manually installing and configuring it? unless you have any reason for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page)

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You must enable php! Check the folder `mods-enabled` in the Apache directory (default: `/etc/apache2/`) to see if you find a file named `php`. I don't remember the extension but I think it's `.so`.

Also check in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` to see if you have any other errors.

Comment: have you run: a2enmod php5

Comment: theres no mods_enabled folder in my apache directory

Comment: @imulsion in my case it was mods-enabled under /etc/apache2/

Comment: In my case for php7, I had to do `a2enmod php7.0` and it solved my problem. Took entire day to reach this post somehow !

Comment: There is no file called `php` in `mods-enabled`, what now? This answer does not explain stuff

Comment: i only see `.conf` and `.load` files in the mods-enabled directory. running `a2enmod php7.0` gives me the following errors: `Considering conflict php5 for php7.0`, `Considering conflict mpm_worker for mpm_prefork`, etc...and apache2 restart fails

Comment: @Black
check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37551253/5864034
as mentioned here and in the error itself, you have to disable the mpm_event first...

Answer (score 108):

Wow, lots of solutions here! Here's what I did on **Ubuntu 16.04**:

```
sudo apt-get install php libapache2-mod-php
sudo a2enmod mpm_prefork && sudo a2enmod php7.0
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Worked for me by adding `--reinstall` to apt-get. Might php module/apache installation was dirty.

Comment: This worked for me on Digital Ocean's Ubuntu 16.04 server Thanks

Comment: this gives me the following errors: `Considering conflict php5 for php7.0`, `Considering conflict mpm_worker for mpm_prefork`, etc...and apache2 restart fails

Comment: If you get `Considering conflict php5 for php7.2` go to `/etc/apache2/mods-available` and delete `php5.*`

Comment: this worked for me (Ubuntu 20.04.2) without executing the second (a2enmod) command

Answer (score 55):

For PHP 7 (May apply to previous versions as well), but I had to do this:

Add this to the bottom of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Run this from the terminal:

```
sudo a2dismod mpm_event && sudo a2enmod mpm_prefork && sudo a2enmod php7
```

Then don't forget to restart Apache so it knows you changed stuff:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

This is a summary from: https://www.atlantic.net/community/howto/try-php7-lamp-ubuntu-14-04/

Comment: I had to do this for PHP 5.6 on OSX El Capitan. (Using stock apache, but homebrew php56)

Comment: Works on Windows too (meaning you don't have to run the terminal commands on Windows) Thanks for saving me endless searches.

Comment: when installing from source, this filesmatch was required. (the config and make etc. enables the module in httpd.conf for me, but didnt add this one.)

Comment: There's a billion comments in the sample httpd.conf file; can anyone explain why there isn't one for php? It's not a rarely used thing.

Comment: @Danial https://httpd.apache.org/support.html has a number methods where you can find docs, report bugs, and ask questions (such as why isn't there a sane example of using PHP in httpd.conf?)

Comment: I just ran into the same problem with my PHP files downloading instead of rendering the page on an Apache local host and this fixed it for me. Very helpful! Thanks!

Comment: This solution also works for WampServer on Windows running PHP 5.6.

Comment: For ubuntu 20.04 / PHP 7.4  I had to run this slight variation:

sudo a2dismod mpm_event && sudo a2enmod mpm_prefork && sudo a2enmod php7.4

Apart from that, worked smoothly.

Answer (score 27):

open the file

`/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`

and change

```
#LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

into

```
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

So just uncoment the PHP module load in `httpd.conf`

Comment: In my case the line started with php7_module - but otherwise this worked for me!

Answer (score 8):

[I found this to solve my related problem.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/407744/apache-doesnt-execute-php-files-but-makes-me-download-them) I added it to the relevant `<Directory>` section:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_admin_flag engine on
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 7):

A different answer that worked for me. Is that, to install `[sudo] apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5.X`

Comment: Mine was similar. I did "sudo apt-cache search ^libapache2 | grep php" which finds the relevant packages and then installed "sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php". libapache2-mod-php7.0 was already installed.

Answer (score 7):

> ## **Apache shows php code instead of executing Issue fixed**
>
> **1. Opened php5.6 conf or php7.x conf**
>
> **# following command:**
>
> **$ sudo vi /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.6.conf**
>
> ## 2. Commented following lines
>
> [image]
>
> ## 3. Restarted the server
>
> **$ sudo service apache2 restart**
>
> ## 4 Enjoy :)

Answer (score 5):

Add following configuration to `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

And restart the `apache` via `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: Thanks! I've firgured it out thanks to [this guide](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-fix-apache-2-not-executing-php-files/). Mine 1st line was exactly `<FilesMatch ".+\.ph(ar|p|tml)$">`, and a file containing it was */etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.3.conf*

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to others on this thread for their suggestions. Following the steps mentioned I found that the apache server was not able to start reporting a syntax error in a `load` file in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled`. Turns out that both php7.0 and php7.1 were enabled.

```
a2dismod php7.0
systemctl restart apache2
```

and php is rendered correctly again.

Answer (score 3):

Alright if you've tried what you've been told above or earlier(which are possible reasons) and it still displays the code instead of executing it then there is one thing which you are doing wrong that hasn't been addressed.
The url you used to access your php code; some people try to execute their php code by just dragging the .php file into the web browser. this is wrong practice and could lead to this kind of problem.
if you have saved a file as "test.php" in the C://wamp/www folder then you must access this file this way:
localhost://test.php.
this kind of mistake will arise when you access it this way: localhost://wamp/www/test.php

Answer (score 3):

If you are a ubuntu user, after installing apache must run the following command in fresh installation

```
sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt
```

In my case works fine.

Comment: on my case it was on php7.0 I had to run `sudo apt-get install php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0-mcrypt`

Answer (score 3):

Posting what worked for me in case in helps someone down the road, though it is an unusual case.

I had set a handler to force my web host to use a higher version of php than their default. There's was 5.1, but I wanted 5.6 so I had this:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler php56-cgi
</FilesMatch>
```

in my .htaccess file.

When trying to run my site locally, having that in there caused php code to be output to the browser. Removing it solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

For PHP7 and Apache2.4, this is all you need to do:

```
sudo vim /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Go to the very bottom and insert the following (all by itself):

```
<FilesMatch "\.*">
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Then, restart Apache to load the new configuration:

```
sudo service httpd restart
```

Apache will now execute all HTTP/S requests with PHP.  If all you have are html, css, and php files, then this will work fine for you.  If you have other languages running, then you'll need to tailor the file matching to your situation.  I've tested this with phpMyAdmin and it works fine.

None of that other stuff all the people are talking about here was necessary for me.  When I put the "AddType Application....." thing in the correct spot, Apache just told me that that module was already loaded and skipped it.

More information can be found here:  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#filesmatch

My install was done as follows:

```
sudo yum install -y httpd24 php70 mysql56-server php70-mysqlnd
```

You should also read this, if you haven't:  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html#when

Comment: The folder `/etc/httpd` doesn't exist for me

Comment: Are you in a Linux environment?  If you're OS is Linux and you're running Apache 2.4, then it should be there.

Comment: Yes, I don't know if I'm with 2.4 but I am with apache2. Should I install httpd service ? (apache works fine)

Comment: You'll need to find/troubleshoot the location of your httpd.conf file separately.  That is a separate issue from what is being addressed here.

Answer (score 2):

You could delete your *.htaccess* file and let the system creates a new (blank or basic) one. It may be that some lines you added are incorrect statements, or something else inside may cause the problem. You can then add line by line from your old *.htaccess* file to see what caused the problem.

That worked for me. The lines telling machine not to display php extensions were problem in my case (*RewriteCond* and *RewriteRule*). My old *.htaccess* file worked just fine on a shared server, but this issue appeared when I switched to VPS.

Comment: Also if you run into the CORS stupidity: run `sudo a2enmod headers` and `sudo a2enmod rewrite` (don't forget to restart Apache).

Answer (score 2):

This was happening to me also when running $_POST in MAMP. All of my .ini and httpd files were all set up correctly. If you are doing form handling and you have an html document and posting the info to a php formhandler running $POST, make sure that you are running the html file from localhost via your server, and not just locally.

This was a shortcut I did to run html documents, by just clicking the html file in my directory and launching in my web browser, when in reality to check if php is being processed in your form, you must run your html through your servers. A very simple protocol that I overlooked.

Example:

Wrong: `file:///Applications/MAMP/htdocs/form/form.html`

Right: `http://localhost:your port number/form/form.html`

Now the php should be processed once you click your submit button

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me:

In active httpd.conf, find

```
<IfModule mime_module>
...
</IfModule>
```

It was missing the following

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
```

After restarting apache, .php files are correctly parsed.

Answer (score 1):

if the module userdir is enabled and your site is in a userdir (~/public_html) you must check /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.conf.
The following part makes it work (on Ubuntu 14.10 utopic):

```
# Running PHP scripts in user directories is disabled by default
# 
# To re-enable PHP in user directories comment the following lines
# (from <IfModule ...> to </IfModule>.) Do NOT set it to On as it
# prevents .htaccess files from disabling it.

# <IfModule mod_userdir.c>
#     <Directory /home/*/public_html>
#        php_admin_flag engine Off
#    </Directory>
# </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

none of the above applied or worked for me... PHP7, Apache Httpd 2.2 on CentOS 6

fact is, I installed (all with yum) php BEFORE Apache... you must do the reverse: always install Apache first, then PHP, and then it works...
Indeed, you are likely missing `libphp7.so` and `libphp7-zts.so` in `/etc/httpd/modules/`

I was able to recover anyhow without UNinstalling PHP. I did add the magic line in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`: `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php` 
And then run: `yum install php php-mysql`

Answer (score 1):

I tried a number of the solutions above however the fix in our scenario was to install the fpm-module.

We had installed httpd before php which may have had something to do with the issue, but to resolve we installed the following:

## yum module install php:7.2

This installed the php-fpm-7.2.11-4.module+el8.1.0+5443+bc1aeb77.x86_64.rpm module which we then enabled by:

## systemctl enable --now php-fpm

From that point we left the /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf as default and restarted httpd

## service httpd restart

Then everything worked.

Hope this helps, took way longer than it should have to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

For CentOS using httpd this saved my day

```
// install mod php to enable httpd load php files
yum install mod_php
systemctl restart httpd
```

Comment: Please explain how that works and why it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, caused by the Debian/ Ubuntu default configuration of module `suphp`. It contained `suPHP_Engine off` for whole /usr/share, which resulted in the php sources being shown in the browser. Deactivating with `a2dismod suphp` was the interim solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. When I run a php file, the web browser showed me the php code instead of execute it. I had tried many times: uninstall/reinstall the wampserver64, working around the PHP/Apache settings/modules, etc. After 2 days: I realised that when I tried to run the php file within the notepad++ by pressing the default combination "ctrl + alt + shift + R" for chrome. It was trying to execute my php file like: "file///C:/wamp64/www/bla/bla.." in my chrome's address bar. That was my problem. I made the changes according to page [Configuring Notepad++ to run php on localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536238/configuring-notepad-to-run-php-on-localhost). My problem was solved. But after 2 days..

Answer (score 0):

Run Xampp (apache) as administrator. In google chrome type:

`localhost/<insert folder name here>/<insert file name>`

i.e. if folder you created is "LearnPhp", file is "chapter1.php" then type

`localhost/LearnPhp/chapter1.php`

I created this folder in the xampp folder in the htdocs folder which gets created when you download xampp.

Answer (score 0):

Debian 9 solution:

```
touch /etc/apache2/conf-available/php.conf
```

Add to file next lines:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    </IfModule>
    <FilesMatch ".+\.php$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php.c>
    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    </IfModule>
    <FilesMatch ".+\.php$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Then run:

```
a2enconf php && service apache2 restart
```

Comment: This worked for me, but not initially. I'm running web content in user directories, which is disabled by default. To enable that, see the last section in `/etc/apache2/mods-available/php7.2.conf`

Answer (score 0):

Some times if you have php version conflicts it happens 
To overcome that please follow the below steps

Step 1 : Yum list installed | grep 'php'

> if you have multiple versions of php like php 5.6 and php 7.0 this confilict will happens

Step 2 : yum remove **your php version **

Step 3 : Then restart the apapche `/etc/init.d/httpd restart` or `service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 0):

This [solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1000700) worked for me. I purged apache2 and reinstall. It happened after purge and install. If it is the first install, you would not face this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case with PHP7.3 Apache2.4 Ubuntu 18.04 I had to execute:

```
$ a2enmod actions fastcgi alias proxy_fcgi
```

Answer (score 0):

Do your other sites/subdirectories work? Is it just a single dir that shows this behavior?

Then check for syntax error in your index.php. If you miss the very first character in a PHP-file: the "<" in "<?php", then the browser shows the rest of the file as it would be a text-file.

---

Example:

```
?php
phpinfo(); 
?>
```

Then the browser shows just "?php phpinfo(); ?>" instead of the output of phpinfo().

Answer (score 0):

If you're using termux and apachectl command complains about not finding libphp.so or other shared objects files the answer may be to rf comment remove the usr ($HOME) directory which it will reinstall when you reopen termux or you can do apt-file search shared_object_filename.so to locate the missing libphp.so file and ln -s to that where the Apache is looking for it. Plus when you edit httpd.conf to include mod PHP the name and path to that module are important. Note: simply changing the module name from PHP 7 module to PHP module according to the .so-named module version could do the trick for you

Answer (score -1):

#### Centos 7, PHP 8, Apache 2

I've recently upgraded a centos server to use php 8.

After the upgrade php had stopped working and apache started serving me the php code as text.

Having spent a good while looking for which config setting had not updated I tracked it down to this:

in `/etc/httpd/conf.d`

```
<IfModule  mod_php7.c>
```

needed changing to:

```
<IfModule  mod_php.c>
```

There are other places that you may see the `mod_php7` check that could probably be updated to the `mod_php` variant but this one definitely fixed it for me.

Don't forget to restart the server afterwards.