# Why is my contact form taking me to contact.php rather than sending an email to me?

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts

I'm a complete noob about web development. I have an one page HTML template that I was trying to edit as per my requirements. It has a contact form that I want people to use to send me an email. I set my email address as $to, but when I was testing the contact form, it didn't send an email to my address. Rather than that, it took me to the page contact.php and I could see all the html and php code. I'm attaching the codes for the contact form. Can anyone tell me what could possibly go wrong and how to fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

HTML Code:

```
<form id="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="contact.php">
<div class="row-fluid">
<p class="span6"><input id="username" name="username" type="text" tabindex="1" value=""     placeholder="Name (required)"></p>
<p class="span6"><input id="email" name="email" type="text" tabindex="2" value="" placeholder="E-mail (required)"></p>
</div>
<div class="row">
<p class="span6"><textarea id="message" name="message" tabindex="4" rows="6" placeholder="Message (required)"></textarea></p>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="span2">
<button id="sending" type="submit" class="btn btn-embossed btn-large btn-primary" data-send="Sending...">Submit</button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

PHP Code:

(Note to the author: You can start your PHP code below:)

```
<?php
?>
```

Please click on the link to see the code. I can't post an image as I am new here. https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPHYH.jpg

Comment: I don't get it.. Your form action is contact.php but that is not what you want?

Comment: "I set my email address as $to".. much more explanation needed

Comment: The image you posted. What file is that? index.php or contact.php?

Comment: I think I just got it. As Chris Barcroft said the server was not processing PHP correctly. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your server is not processing PHP correctly.  There's nothing wrong with your HTML form, assuming contact.php is indeed the action page you want - you just need to get your server/computer to handle PHP properly.  Check [this answer for more info.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142172/apache-shows-php-code-instead-of-executing)