# PHP extension which leads to page not found

Tags: php

I created a PHP page and uploaded the file. but trying to access it without .php extension like below link:-

https://www.astropackgulf.com/food-inspection-system

its showing error 404 page

only with full .php extension, it's showing the page. link below

https://www.astropackgulf.com/food-inspection-system.php

I don't want to show the .php extension. I tried in .htaccess which I know the code to redirect to no extension PHP page but where I get only this 404 error.

the link worked previosly fine for last 3 months...but now this error shows

Comment: If that link worked for the last three months, what has changed?

Comment: Did You change the apache settings on Your server? This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33933480/how-to-have-files-without-extensions-treated-as-php-in-apache

Answer (score 0):

I know this may sound very dumb if it is not true but did you make a directory called food-inspection-system and made a file inside called index.php?

If you didn't, than you should make a directory called food-inspection-system and paste your food-inspection-system.php inside it and rename it to index.php.

If that was not the case at all and you did what I asked above, than it could be that the permissions of the file are configured wrong, if you have ftp access, try to connect to your server with [filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=client), select the food-inspection-system directory right click, click on change permissions and set them to 777.

One of these things should fix your issue