# Direct path to index.php displays a source code

Tags: php, linux, apache

There is apache server with installed php. All php files are executed correctly and display html content. 
But I have an only problem with index.php.
Page like **http://localhost/folder/** displays correctly executed index.php, but **http://localhost/folder/index.php** shows a source.

What the problem it could be?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142172/apache-shows-php-code-instead-of-executing

Comment: this is not the same problem, all php files are executed, and even index.php is executed when you go in folder which contains it, it is only the problem when you open direct path to index.php

Comment: For your case, it already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-i-can-see-it-on-source-code-of-page