# Laravel 5.1 Moving from one Ubuntu 14.04 to another

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.1, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to moving my Laravel 5.1 app from one Ubuntu 14.04 server to another.  I have updated the installed composer, database info, the app key, cleared cache and the sites-enabled points to the public directory.  However instead of app up and running all I see is the text of the index.php file.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually turns out it was the apache configuration issue.  The site below helped.  I ended up creating aliases so that I am no longer shown the directory listings.

http://mackhankins.com/blog/laravel-5-virtual-host-for-an-apache-subdirectory

Answer (score 1):

If you're just seeing the code of the index.php file, then I suppose your php is not installed properly.
That is why php code of index.php file is not being executed and it is shown as plain text only.

Try running this command on terminal

```
php -v
```

Comment: It is installed.  Please see below:PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.20 (cli) (built: Oct  3 2016 13:00:37) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies

Comment: I installed all the PHP and relevant dependencies on a new Ubuntu 14.04 EC2 server.  It connects to my RDS instance with a drupal  installation and I can build content. .htaccess works fine too.   The path is /var/www/html/drupal   Then i created another directory parallel to drupal called laravel  /var/www/html/laravel.  I copied over my app to the laravel director.  Also updated the .env with my database credentials and created a new Application key.   Cleared cache. Ran composer update.  But see a white screen.  If in the route home (/) I add echo 'Welcome to my site'; it works.  Thoughts?

Comment: To clarify further  if I go to the /var/www/html/laravel via browser i.e. http://myipdadress/laravel/ all i see is my directory listing

Comment: @JotiBasi go to yourip/laravel/public or much better choice would be that you run `php artisan serve` in the root of your laravel project

Answer (score 0):

If you are using apache it may refer to this question:

[Apache shows php code instead of executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142172/apache-shows-php-code-instead-of-executing)

If you are using nginx, you may now config the nginx correctly, and it server *.php just as static file .