# Ajax success function returns index.php verbatim

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

What am I doing wrong?

For some reason the success function's html.responseText is a verbatim copy of the domain's index.php. This call isn't even made in index.php, nor does it address it—what's going on?

The Ajax:

```
var k = '123abc';
$.ajax({
    URL: 'php/dbInsertKey.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: {
        key: k
    },
    success: function(html){
        console.log(html);
    }
});
```

dbInsertKey.php:

```
$key = (string) $_POST['key'];
echo ($key);
```

instead of returning '123abc', it returns a string that contains the domain's index.php, line for line. And for what it's worth, this happens no matter what the supplied URL is: 'php/nonsense.lol' will give the same result.

Comment: if the url is wrong, and index is the defult 404 page ... thats what happens

Comment: I've tried every url there is. This file and dbInsertKey.php are in the same folder. if I take away the 'php/' it will still give me the index as responseText

Comment: perhaps you could tell us a little about the "server environment" ... apache? nginx? something else?

Comment: Apache. Other files make and receive ajax calls perfectly as we speak. It's just this one.

Answer (score 2):

## Answer (updated)

You are using uppercase URL in your call to jquery - it should be lowercase url . I still don't see how this would lead to you seeing your php file, but it seems like it may be somehow a factor

### My Original Answer (still relevant for others finding this in a similar situation)

> Sounds like your webserver may not be configured correctly for PHP (or you don't even have PHP installed)
>
> See here for more help diagnosing/fixing: [Apache shows php code instead of executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142172/apache-shows-php-code-instead-of-executing)

Comment: It does sound like that, but I've been using it for years, doing exactly this type of stuff.

Comment: I would still investigate, Assume nothing, rule out the obvious first - You mention that other files work, but at the same time this happens for any URL - those statements seem at odds with each other, could you explain a little more

Comment: index.php contains a menu, and a div in which content is loaded via ajax calls from other php's. Think "settings.php" being loaded into `$('#menu_window')` when a button is clicked. Settings.php in turn contains other ajax calls that insert or retreieve stuff from the database. This has worked fine, and is working fine as we speak. But this particular file won't for the love of god receive as much as a `echo ('test')` from the called upon dbInsertKey.php.

Comment: You are using uppercase `URL` in your call to jquery - it should be lowercase [`url`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) . I still don't see how this would lead to you seeing your php file, but it seems like it may be somehow a factor

Comment: @VHK no worries, it's easy to miss these things, when symptoms point you to a more obvious place to look. I have updated my answer - I would be interested to know if you ever figure out why it resulted in you seeing your PHP though. That sounds slightly worrying from a security perspective.

Answer (score 0):

The `URL` argument should be in lowercase. Thanks, Theo, for noticing that.