# Apache does not compile php

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, apache2

I just installed a fresh ubuntu system from [here](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/) (mini.iso)
I choosed no extras at all during the installation process.

These are all the commands which I have executed this far:
(Ignore 4 - 8)
[image]

Now I wrote a simple PHP test script (**/var/www/html/index.php**)

```
<?php

echo "Hello World";

?>
```

However, after calling this page from another computer, I literally get the output from the file, instead of the compiled php.

**Output:**

```
<?php

echo "Hello World";

?>
```

I have already restarted apache2, no change.

**Apache version:**

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Jul 15 2016 15:32:47
```

**PHP version:**

```
PHP 7.0.16-4+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) (built: Mar  2 2017 13:50:00) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.16-4+deb.sury.org~trusty+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

**Linux version:**

Linux linux 3.13.0-110-generic #157-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 20 11:55:25 UTC 2017 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

I already searched the internet, some other user sayed to check if the PHP module is loaded by checking the file `httpd.conf`, but there is no such file. I searched it by using `find / -name "httpd.conf"` which gave no results.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142172/apache-shows-php-code-instead-of-executing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install PHP apache2 module to work with PHP. You can install `libapache2-mod-php` from your terminal by typing the command

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php
```

After that restart your apache. It will solve your problem.

Comment: That solved the problem, thank you very much. Note: You don't have to restart the apache2 server, since this happens automatically during the installation.