# aws php code not execute only show plain code

Tags: php, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

i'm new in AWS and Ubuntu
i've facing a issue to execute php file on aws,
i've already install php and apache.

[image]

when I access aws it show file is there,but this file in directory

```
var/www/html/phpinfo.php
```

[image]

But when I delete file from `var/www/html/phpinfo.php` and past  var/www/phpinfo.php no file show aws public IP, but on var/www/html/phpinfo.php it show plain php code

[image]

**Update**

follow these [step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142172/apache-shows-php-code-instead-of-executing) 
in apache2,conf

SetHandler application/x-httpd-php

then using terminal

```
sudo a2dismod mpm_event && sudo a2enmod mpm_prefork && sudo a2enmod php7
```

it show following message

```
considering conflict php5 for php7
module php7.0 already enabled
```

**Enable Modes**

```
etc/apache2/mods-enabled ls
```

I find these also

```
php7.0.conf and php7.0.load
```

Comment: i already spend 1 day to fixing server and setup please help do not vote down

Comment: The problem is that the file don't appear, that PHP code is not executed, or both?

Comment: Please never post ephemeral content like paste.ofcode.org on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default apache2 point to **/var/www/html/**
So if you put your file in **/var/www/** it's normal that you don't seen the file.

To change this you can edit your **apache2.conf** file

```
vi /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

For your second issue (apache2 showing plain php code)
It means that apache2 don't pass the code to your php interpreter.

Make sure that **php is enable** by checking that these 2 links are in the **mod-enable** folder in your **/etc/apache2**

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   29 août   3 14:30 php7.0.conf -> ../mods-available/php7.0.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   29 août   3 14:30 php7.0.load -> ../mods-available/php7.0.load
```

if you don't have these links, type the following and try again:

```
a2enmod php7.0
service apache2 restart
```

.

Comment: a2enmod php7.0
service apache2 restart Done
mods-available/
php7.0.conf
php7.0.log
But still  show index of empty no file there... but var/www/phpinfo.php already there

Comment: module php7.0 already enabled message show

Answer (score -1):

Installing Apache and PHP is not enough, you also have to configure Apache properly to handle its *mod_php* when a file with the ".php" extension is requested.

You can find tons of articles about how to do that here and there on the Web :-) , but here is a good example:

- http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#apache-with-mod-php-php-cgi

Comment: Bro i've also try but nothing happen same index.of empty show ..