# Centos 6 - PHP 7.1 Does not execute in the browser

Tags: php, linux, command-line, server, centos6

Originally, on the server was PHP 5 install, I've uninstalled it along with apache. Then I installed Apache and PHP 7.1. Now, I can execute PHP from the command line but not from the browser. Html files do work in the browser.

Could you please tell me, is there anything I need to install or configure? I've tried to add module of PHP in httpd.conf but no result.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache shows php code instead of executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142172/apache-shows-php-code-instead-of-executing)

Comment: I'm trying to run Php 7.1 on Centos 6, not Php 5 on Ubuntu. Thanks.

Comment: Yes.. but the problem to me sounds a lot like Apache is not set up properly which the topic describes so try to read past just versions.

Comment: What is show in the log file `/var/log/httpd/error.log` when you try and call `php` from a browser.