# While running PHP file it is printing the programming code instead of output

Tags: php

This is my code that I am working with

```
//Windows Authentication
<?php
$serverName = "IE3PDT1QK88G5"; 
connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"MIN-MAK MRO ");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
 echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
 echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
sqlsrv_close( $conn);  
?>
```

Comment: What is your output ?

Comment: this code is printing in browser too

Comment: You can re-setup your environment i.e. Apache/PHP. (only if nothing worked!!!)

Comment: The problem is that php is not elaborating your php files. This may depend on a misconfiguration of your server or on a wrong file extension. Are you using a lamp or lemp environment?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache shows php code instead of executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142172/apache-shows-php-code-instead-of-executing)

Comment: iam using lamp @roberto Bisello

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are turning on your server.
Printed php code on browser can be caused by the server is down.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your file should be saved with`.php` extension instead of `.html`.

Answer (score 0):

check the apache configuration:

- ensure that in your httpd.conf you have the line `LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so` or `LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7.so` if you're using php7
- check that in apache configuration there is something similar to

  ```
  <FilesMatch \.php$>
      SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
  </FilesMatch>
  ```
- check that starting apache you don't have error messages (some broken path or some mistype in configuration or similar)

source: http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php