# how to overcome php file if in open appear like this?

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, ubuntu

my vps ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS and PHP php version 7.1.17-1 + ubuntu14.04.1 + deb.sury.org + 1
if i open my web link it appears this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
*/
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

where is this wrong? or less complementary supplements that support php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache shows php code instead of executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142172/apache-shows-php-code-instead-of-executing)

Comment: Either your server is misconfigured or you are accessing your file directly through the filesystem.

Comment: I've got the solution, but when I want to install wordpress appears this: `Error establishing a database connection`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running the file directly the php will show
You need to run php files on a local server/ online server then only it will do what is supposed to do, otherwise it will show the php code

Comment: I've got the solution, but when I want to install wordpress appears this: Error establishing a database connection