# Auto-loader error showing after Ubuntu upgrade - Laravel not working

Tags: laravel, apache2, ubuntu-18.04

The error shows up when accessing my Laravel project:

```
*/ 

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true)); 

/* 
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
| Register The Auto Loader
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for 
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it 
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual 
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels great to relax.
| 
*/ 

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php'; 

/*
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights. 
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it 
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users. 
| 
*/ 

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php'; 

/*
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
| Run The Application
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
| 
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request 
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to 
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative 
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them. 
| 
*/ 

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class); 
$response = $kernel->handle( 
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);
$response->send(); 
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Comment: hope this will help you [github issue link](https://github.com/snipe/snipe-it/issues/5611) , [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142172/apache-shows-php-code-instead-of-executing/12142315#12142315)