# Securely communicate with mysql server (MariaDB) using javascript and php (NO jQuery)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to achieve two things:
(1) Get text from a contenteditable div, use javascript to send that text to php, use php to send that data to a MySQL database and save it
(2) retrieve the saved data/text and reinsert it into a contentedtiable div

All of this whilst NOT using jQuery

What I've got so far:

index.html

```
<body>
    <div contenteditable="true" id="editable"></div>
    <button onClick="send_data();">Save text</button>
    <button onClick="retrieve_data();">Get text</button>
</body>
```

javascript.js

```
function send_data() {
    var php_file = "connection.php";
    var http_connection = new XMLHttpRequest();

    http_connection.open("POST", php_file, true);

    http_connection.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(http_connection.readyState == 4 && http_connection.status == 200) {
            alert(http_connection.responseText);
        }
    }

   http_connection.send(document.getElementById('editable').innerText);
}

function retrieve_data() {
    // I do not know what to put here
}
```

connection.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "mysql_user";
$password = "secure_password";
$dbname = "some_database";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

if(!conn) {
    echo 'No connection';
}

if(!mysqli_select_db($conn,'some_database')) {
    echo "No database";
}

$some_val = $_GET['text']

$sql = "SELECT text FROM some_database";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

echo $result;

$conn->close();

?>
```

Edit: what my code fails to do is to upload text as well as recieve text.

Comment: So you make a get request to the server and get the data.

Comment: Which error/problem did you have with that code?

Comment: @epascarello what do you mean? please check my post again I have updated it

Comment: `console.log("readystate="+http_connection.readyState+" | status="+http_connection.status);` see what you're actually receiving and take it from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some problems in the js:

- `http_c` is not defined
- `readyState` is spelled incorrectly
- the `send` method needs to be *outside* the `onreadystatechange` callback

Once those things are corrected, program should give different, which is not to say expected, result.

Other things:

The js is sending a 'POST' request. The php is looking for `$_GET["text"]` which will give undefined error.  I'm speculation this `$sql = "SELECT text FROM some_database";` will fail (if it reaches that line) unless there is a table in the database named "some_database".

Suggest, for starters, get the ajax working by short-circuiting the code in `connection.php` to something like

```
echo "You are here";
exit;
```

Then gradually working forward between the js and the php until programs give you what you want.

Comment: Changing the code according to the problems you highlighted does not result in any change. I am not getting any alert from `alert(http_connection.responseText);` nor is data being sent to the MySQL server ran by PhpMyAdmin on apache on a linux computer

Comment: answer amened with more info

Comment: I am unable to retrieve "You are here". My http_connection.status is always 0. I have CORS disabled. When I remove the check for status == 200 and logs the retrieved text I get the whole php code, including the "<?php .... ?>" part. Why am I getting status 0, no errors in dev. console and the whole php code?

Comment: showing the "whole php code" could indicate that [php is not enabled on the web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142172/apache-shows-php-code-instead-of-executing#12142315). When I execute that js (loaded in script tags in the html verbatim), with the 2 line php file as described in the answer on an (local) IIS server, it gives the expected alert.