# How can I have if/else condition inside a large php string variable?

Tags: php, html

I have a large php string variable.  I want to put php if/else condition inside it, so the edit and delete buttons to be displayed only to the author of the comment and not to everyone, but my code is not working.  I used a colon to define the if/else condition, but it doesn’t work.  Regular if/else condition also doesn’t work.

Here is my php code:

```
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

$if = "if ($user_id == $row['user_id']): ";

$else = "else: ";

$endif = "endif; ";

foreach($result as $row)
{
 $output .= '
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">'.$row["comment"].'</div>

  <div class="panel-footer">

     '. $if .'

     <form  class="input-group form-row" action="comment_delete1.php" method="post" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
         <input type="hidden" name="comment_id" id="comment_id" value="'.$row["comment_id"].'" />
         <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" value="'.$row["user_id"].'" />
         <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="submit btn btn-default" value="Delete" />
        </div>
      </form>   

      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default edit" id="'.$row["comment_id"].'" >Edit</button>  

    '. $else .'

      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default reply" id="'.$row["comment_id"].'" >Reply</button>

    '. $endif .'

    </div>
</div>
 ';
}
echo $output;
```

Comment: `$if`? `$else`? those aren't conditions, those are variables. The variables will not be evaluated as a construct, they will be evaluated as a part of the string.

Comment: Yes, I put the conditions inside variables.  I also did put the conditions directly inside the string, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Because you're just making it all a string which will not be evaluated.

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: See the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

If we put conditions inside php string or heredoc, php will treat them as string and will display them on the screen as string.  So we cannot have conditions inside string.

I put the if else conditions outside the php string variable, and I created two php string variables, one with delete and edit buttons, and the other one without delete and edit buttons.  So `if` the user_id is equal to session user id, the php string variable with delete and edit buttons will be displayed. And, `else if` the user_id is not equal to session user id, the php string variable without delete and edit buttons will be displayed.  The php string variable will be echoed at the end of all conditions.

Here is the php code:

```
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

foreach($result as $row) {

   if ($row['user_id'] === $user_id) {

$output .= '
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">'.$row["comment"].'</div>

  <div class="panel-footer">
     <form  class="input-group form-row" action="comment_delete1.php" method="post" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
         <input type="hidden" name="comment_id" id="comment_id" value="'.$row["comment_id"].'" />
         <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" value="'.$row["user_id"].'" />
         <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="submit btn btn-default" value="Delete" />
        </div>
      </form>   

      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default edit" id="'.$row["comment_id"].'" >Edit</button>  
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default reply" id="'.$row["comment_id"].'" >Reply</button>
    </div>
</div>
 ';

    } else if ($row['user_id'] !== $user_id) {

$output .= '
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">'.$row["comment"].'</div>

  <div class="panel-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default reply" id="'.$row["comment_id"].'" >Reply</button>
  </div>
 </div>
 ';
    }
}

echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this correctly the condition must be evaluated:

```
foreach($result as $row)
{
 $output .= '
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">'.$row["comment"].'</div>

  <div class="panel-footer">';

if ($user_id == $row['user_id']) {

     $output .=  '<form  class="input-group form-row" action="comment_delete1.php" method="post" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
         <input type="hidden" name="comment_id" id="comment_id" value="'.$row["comment_id"].'" />
         <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" value="'.$row["user_id"].'" />
         <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="submit btn btn-default" value="Delete" />
        </div>
      </form>   

      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default edit" id="'.$row["comment_id"].'" >Edit</button>';

} else {

      $output .= '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default reply" id="'.$row["comment_id"].'" >Reply</button>
    </div>
</div>
 ';
    }
}
echo $output;
```

This is really not a good way to do this and you should consider refactoring your code to make this much neater and easier to read.

Comment: I tried it, but the if/else statement itself is displayed on the website, and it doesn't work.

Comment: The PHP code is displayed? If it is you are either not running a web server or you're accessing the files incorrectly or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142172/apache-shows-php-code-instead-of-executing

Comment: What URL are you using to access your PHP file?

Comment: It is local host in Windows PC.

Comment: Do you have PHP configured to run on your local web server?

Comment: Yes, I have been using it for a long time.  I don't think there is any problem with my XAMPP.

Comment: If you're seeing the PHP code in your output then there is an issue with XAMPP

Comment: So the issue shows itself when I put conditions inside php string variable?   There are multiple conditions all over my program, and I never had any issue.

Comment: If you did it just like I wrote it and the server is working properly you would not see any PHP code at all.

Comment: Do you have the PHP tags in that page?

Comment: It shows the if else statements then the reply, edit, delete buttons.  Except that one closing bracket is after the reply button.

Comment: it shows this:  `if ($user_id == $row["user_id"]) { 
} else {` Reply button `}` Edit button, Delete button

Comment: Does the page have the opening PHP tag? `<?php`?

Comment: Yes, it does.  There are other codes before the php string variable.

Comment: Maybe you should post the code of the whole page in your question.

Comment: I don't think it helps.  What particular Apache file should I look for?

Comment: httpd.conf is the apache file where Apache is configured.

Comment: What should I change in it?

Comment: I have no idea. You said your XAMPP was working properly and has never had a problem before, so I don't think there is anything to change unless you have modified something.