# Ubuntu18.04, Apache2, php7.4 running but browser still "downloads" index.php

Tags: php, apache2, ubuntu-18.04

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.4 with Apache2 and php7.4.4 in a Oracle VirtualBox to try out some php pages someone made for me. Unfortuanly my Firefox somehow always wants to download index.php instead of running it.

I tried to solved the problem already according to other threats and help pages:

- I added this to

```
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf 
<FilesMatch \.php$>
​SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
​</FilesMatch>
```

- I disabled mpm_event and enabled mpm_prefork
- Restarted apache --> php is still not working
- Tried to install libapache2-mod-php7.4 / phpmyadmin
- Restart apache again

The problem persists, I wonder if something with apache2.conf is still not ok?

Comment: Why did you add the number 2 on `application/x-httpd-php​2`?

Comment: hi, oh thats a prob with the display of my post, it should be  2. i fixed it now

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache shows php code instead of executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142172/apache-shows-php-code-instead-of-executing)