# PHP not showing text

Tags: php, html

im making a google extention but when i try to display some data it just shows the base code

html code to transfer the data

```
<form action="/assinmenttracker.php", method="post">
<br>
<br>    
Name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

and the PHP code

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_POST["fname"]; ?><br>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: seems like your PHP is not running. create a php file with: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and try open in your server to see what he prints.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache shows PHP code instead of executing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142172/apache-shows-php-code-instead-of-executing-it)

Comment: Do you forget the PHP-tags `<?php ... ?>` where you had to place your code inside?

Comment: Remove the comma after `action="/assinmenttracker.php"`