# Laravel apache public index not showing page

Tags: php, laravel, apache, laravel-5

how to solve the laravel on prod server, page is not showing instead the index.php string is shown below is the image attached.

[image index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMEX5.png)

my code on vhost is.

```
  VirtualHost *:80>
  
        ServerName my.server.com
        RewriteEngine On        
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [redirect=301]    
        
    </VirtualHost>
    Listen 443
    
    <VirtualHost *:443>
      
       DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs/OCMS/publics"
        ServerName my.server.com    
        <Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs/OCMS/public>
            Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks               
            AllowOverride all
            allow From All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
        
        Alias /admin "${SRVROOT}/htdocs/OCMS/public"    
        <Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs/OCMS/public">
            Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
            order deny,allow
            AllowOverride all
            allow From All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
        
    </VirtualHost>
```

my code on htaccess is.

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>           
    
        
        # Send Requests To Front Controller...
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
        
        RewriteBase /admin/
    </IfModule>
```

Comment: looks you php-fpm is not set properay

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache shows PHP code instead of executing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142172/apache-shows-php-code-instead-of-executing-it)