# Yii2 advanced index.php not working. In main domain, the code in index.php shows

Tags: php, ubuntu, yii2, apache2, yii2-advanced-app

It works well in my lohalhost, when i try to put on the server this error occured.

**In index.php**

```
<?php defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true); defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

require(__DIR__ . '/_protected/vendor/autoload.php'); require(__DIR__ . '/_protected/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php'); require(__DIR__ . '/_protected/common/config/bootstrap.php'); require(__DIR__ . '/_protected/frontend/config/bootstrap.php');

$config = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/_protected/common/config/main.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/_protected/common/config/main-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/_protected/frontend/config/main.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/_protected/frontend/config/main-local.php') );

$application = new yii\web\Application($config); $application->run();
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on

# hide files and folders
RedirectMatch 404 /_protected
RedirectMatch 404 /\.git
RedirectMatch 404 /composer\.
RedirectMatch 404 /.bowerrc

# If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward the request to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: Are you using Apache? Did you enable php? Run apache2ctl -M and check that there is a php line in the result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache shows PHP code instead of executing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142172/apache-shows-php-code-instead-of-executing-it)

Comment: what error ? there is not exception / error string provided

Answer (score 0):

if your use apache set DocumentRoot /var/www/frontend/web
and add .htaccess file to /var/www/frontend/web with content

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: set to apache config* DocumentRoot /var/www/frontend/web