# Doesn't Render Website on Live server using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

**I am confused to complete the Codeginiter Folder structure upload on the Live server. So, the Website doesn't Render properly**.

Getting Issue Like This in IMAGE.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJz5B.png)

```
<?php
/**
 * CodeIgniter
 *
 * An open-source application development framework for PHP
 *
 * This content is released under the MIT License (MIT)
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2014 - 2019, British Columbia Institute of Technology
 *
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
 * of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
 * in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
 * to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
 * copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
 * furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
 *
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
 * all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
 *
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
 * IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NON-INFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
 * AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES, OR OTHER
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
 * OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
 * THE SOFTWARE.
 *
 * @package CodeIgniter
 * @author  EllisLab Dev Team
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2008 - 2014, EllisLab, Inc. (https://ellislab.com/)
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2014 - 2019, British Columbia Institute of Technology (https://bcit.ca/)
 * @license https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT MIT License
 * @link    https://codeigniter.com
 * @since   Version 1.0.0
 * @filesource
 */

    define('ENVIRONMENT', isset($_SERVER['CI_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['CI_ENV'] : 'development');

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * ERROR REPORTING
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * Different environments will require different levels of error reporting.
 * By default development will show errors but testing and live will hide them.
 */
switch (ENVIRONMENT)
{
    case 'development':
        error_reporting(-1);
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    break;

    case 'testing':
    case 'production':
        ini_set('display_errors', 0);
        if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3', '>='))
        {
            error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & ~E_USER_NOTICE & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED);
        }
        else
        {
            error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_USER_NOTICE);
        }
    break;

    default:
        header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
        echo 'The application environment is not set correctly.';
        exit(1); // EXIT_ERROR
}

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * SYSTEM DIRECTORY NAME
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * This variable must contain the name of your "system" directory.
 * Set the path if it is not in the same directory as this file.
 */
    $system_path = 'system';


    define('APPPATH', $application_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

    // The path to the "views" directory
    if ( ! isset($view_folder[0]) && is_dir(APPPATH.'views'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR))
    {
        $view_folder = APPPATH.'views';
    }
    elseif (is_dir($view_folder))
    {
        if (($_temp = realpath($view_folder)) !== FALSE)
        {
            $view_folder = $_temp;
        }
        else
        {
            $view_folder = strtr(
                rtrim($view_folder, '/\\'),
                '/\\',
                DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
            );
        }
    }
    elseif (is_dir(APPPATH.$view_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR))
    {
        $view_folder = APPPATH.strtr(
            trim($view_folder, '/\\'),
            '/\\',
            DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
        );
    }
    else
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
        echo 'Your view folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: '.SELF;
        exit(3); // EXIT_CONFIG
    }

    define('VIEWPATH', $view_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * LOAD THE BOOTSTRAP FILE
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * And away we go...
 */
require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';
```

We are Remove most of code upper issue.

**Display Index.php file as it's in live server.**

```
I have .htaccess File like code :

RewriteEngine On

DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

so, Any Solution to solve this error and website render Properly on the Live server.

???

Comment: `Issue Like This`...an issue like what, exactly? You haven't explained the problem clearly. "Not render properly" could mean all sorts of different things. What exactly are you seeing on the screen? Provide a screenshot, if you can't explain it easily.

Comment: Try the solutions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142172/apache-shows-php-code-instead-of-executing-it)