# PHP print multiple lines of code instead of execute query and put elements in Database (registration form)

Tags: php, html, sql, database, forms

Hy, im new on php and im trying to make a registration and login form, but he show this code when i click the submit button to submit my user informations to database:

page sign-up.php:

```
<?php
require('functions/database.php');
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
 header("Location:dashboard.html");
}
session_destroy();
session_start();
ob_start();
?>

<html>
[...]
<head>
[...]
<body>
<form role="form text-left" action="sign_up.php" method="POST">
    <div class="mb-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" name="userfirstname" id="userfirstname">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" name="userlastname" id="userlastname">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nickname" name="usernickname" id="usernickname">

    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="userpass" id="userpass">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="userpassconfirm" id="userpassconfirm">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="useremail" id="useremail">

    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Hometown" name="userhometown" id="userhometown">
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
        <input type="submit" class="btn bg-gradient-dark w-100 my-4 mb-2" name="register"></input>
    </div>
        <p class="text-sm mt-3 mb-0">Already have an account? <a href="javascript:;" class="text-dark font-weight-bolder">Sign in</a></p>
</form>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

page sign_up.php:

```
<?
session_start();
require_once('functions/database.php');

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
        // Retrieve Data
        $userfirstname = $_POST['userfirstname'];
        $userlastname = $_POST['userlastname'];
        $usernickname = $_POST['usernickname'];
        $userpassword = md5($_POST['userpass']);
        $useremail = $_POST['useremail'];
        $userhometown = $_POST['userhometown'];

        $query = "SELECT user_email, FROM users WHERE user_email=:email";
        $check = $pdo->prepare($query);
        $check->bindParam(':email', $useremail, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $check->execute();

        $checkquery = $check->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if ($count($checkquery) > 0) {
            $msg = "User alredy registered";

        } else {
            // Insert Data
            $query = "INSERT INTO users(user_firstname, user_lastname, user_nickname, user_password, user_email,  user_hometown) VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :nickname, :password, :email, :hometown)";
            $check = $pdo->prepare($query);
            $check->bindParam(':firstname', $userfirstname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $check->bindParam(':lastname', $userlastname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $check->bindParam(':nickname', $usernickname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $check->bindParam(':password', $userpassword, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $check->bindParam(':email', $useremail, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $check->bindParam(':hometown', $userhometown, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $check->execute();

            if ($check->rowCount() > 0) {
                $msg = "success!";

            } else {
                $msg ="error, try again";
            }
        }
    }
}

echo $msg;
?>
```

error when submit registration form:

```
prepare($query); $check->bindParam(':email', $useremail, PDO::PARAM_STR); $check >execute(); $checkquery = $check->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); if ($count($checkquery) > 0) { $msg = "Utente gia registrato"; } else { // Insert Data $query = "INSERT INTO users(user_firstname, user_lastname, user_nickname, user_password, user_email, user_hometown) VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :nickname, :password, :email, :hometown)"; $check = $pdo->prepare($query); $check->bindParam(':firstname', $userfirstname, PDO::PARAM_STR); $check->bindParam(':lastname', $userlastname, PDO::PARAM_STR); $check->bindParam(':nickname', $usernickname, PDO::PARAM_STR); $check->bindParam(':password', $userpassword, PDO::PARAM_STR); $check->bindParam(':email', $useremail, PDO::PARAM_STR); $check->bindParam(':hometown', $userhometown, PDO::PARAM_STR); $check->execute(); if ($check->rowCount() > 0) { $msg = "utente registrato"; } else { $msg ="utente non registrato"; } } } } echo $msg; ?>
```

if you also have any suggestions for the syntax, comments, it is welcome

Comment: `SELECT user_email, FROM` remove the comma after user_email

Comment: @Ahmed i tryed but didn't change anything :(

Comment: Did you  got the same error?

Comment: @Ahmed yes, same, i worked so long at this project, maybe i need a coffe ahaah

Comment: Have you configured the web server?

Comment: @Ahmed yes, im in localhost, but same error

Comment: Refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142172/apache-shows-php-code-instead-of-executing-it

Answer (score 0):

Please remove "," after user_email in your code.

```
$query = "SELECT user_email FROM users WHERE user_email=:email";
$check = $pdo->prepare($query);
$check->execute(array('email' => $useremail));
```

Comment: I tryed, but nothing change :(

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ja/pdo.prepare.php  You can see it.