# Opencart on OpenServer apache2 in Ubuntu 22.04 not working. Showing only some part of code

Tags: php, apache2, opencart

I have configured an opencart on open server apache2 in Ubuntu Linux 22.04, following this guide:

`https://cloudcone.com/docs/article/install-opencart-on-ubuntu-18-04-server/`

but, when i going to browser, there only some part of php code! And please, note, that at all dont know php lang, but, if it will help, i will figure it out. Any assist would be appreciated!)[this is how looking opencart on my local server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehQmR.png)

I tried to fix it by myself, was looking for any bugs in configs, was loogin for on it in google, but i couldnt.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache shows PHP code instead of executing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142172/apache-shows-php-code-instead-of-executing-it)