XAMPP: PHP homepage shows 404 page not found, but HTML homepage works
I have tried to setup XAMPP server for testing my own WP website locally on my Windows 11. XAMPP was installed correctly - I use default apache port 80 because there is no conflict with other apps, and a DB was imported successfully without an error.
The root directory of my dev site is in C:/xampp/htdocs/test/
a) The followings are working:
    http://localhost
    http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php

b) PHP homepage on local XAMP server displays 404 not found page:
    http://localhost/test/ or http://localhost/test/index.php

c) HTML homepage works:
    http://localhost/test/index.html (I put that index.html in root directory above for testing)

d) Category page is redirected to http://localhost/dashboard/:
    http://localhost/test/cat/services/

-I have tried to configure virtualhost in C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.config:
  <VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/test/"
  ServerName web1.localhost
  </VirtualHost>

-and in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts:
  127.0.0.1       localhost
  127.0.0.1         web1.localhost

But they dont work at all, and even rediects some of the pages above to my live website's homepage.
How can I fix this issue?

do you have directive in apache config to server php files? PHP is a parto of package so it will always work

what directive in php.ini?

check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142172/apache-shows-php-code-instead-of-executing-it

That seems to be for Ubuntu or Linux server; it is not for XAMPP local server

If the path is correct (and it is because tested with simple html file) the problem must be in php engine or configuration. Are there any errors in logs?

thanks. I found this error in error logs: [php7:error] [pid 10436:tid 1884] [client ::1:45789] script 'C:/xampp/htdocs/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat

that page not found does not generate any errors. This error when I tried to login

I renamed .htaccess file, it now shows homepage and wp-login.php also shows up (but redirected to live homepage with page not found 404). other pages show this error "The requested URL was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1h PHP/7.4.12 Server at localhost Port 80"

redirecting to live version - could be problem with wordpress configuration itself (default url setup somewhere). Paste htaccess and errors you have on what urls
